# Create random numbers in a reproducible way and hide generator threading (Using Haskell Monad)

Tags: haskell, random, monads

I need to create random data in Haskell.
I want my code to be:
  a) reproducible from a seed
  b) the threading of generators to be implicit

I understand Monads generally and the way that Random Generators work.
My approach is to thread the generator through the code so I can reproduce the random numbers but want to hide the threading of the generators in a Monad.
I'm thinking that the State Monad is a good approach.

Here's some simple code:

```
type Gen a = State StdGen a

roll :: Gen Int
roll = state $ randomR (1, 6)

roll2 :: Gen Int
roll2 = (+) <$> roll <*> roll

test :: Int -> IO ()
test seed = do
  let gen = mkStdGen seed
  print (evalState roll gen)
  print (evalState roll gen)
  print (evalState roll2 gen)
  print (evalState roll2 gen)
```

I'm trying to use State so that I can push the threading of the generator into the State Monad but the results of roll are the same and results of roll2 are the same.  I can see that this is because I'm passing gen into the functions multiple times so of course it would produce the same output.  So that makes me think I need to get a new generator from each function.  But then I'm back to having to thread the generator through the code which is what I'm trying to avoid by using State.  I feel like I'm missing a trick!

I explored MonadRandom too and that did push the threading away from my code but I couldn't see how to make that approach be reproducible.

I've hunted a lot and tried many things but seem to always either be able to hide the generators OR make the code reproducible but not both.

I'm keen to use a Monad more specific than IO.

I'm also going to build a series of more complex functions which will generate random lists of numbers so I need to have a simple way to make these random functions rely on each other.  I managed that with MonadRandom but again I couldn't see how that could be reproducible.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What did you try with `MonadRandom` that wasn't repeatable?

Comment: [System.IO.Streams.fromGenerator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-streams-1.5.1.0/docs/System-IO-Streams.html#v:fromGenerator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you needn't interleave `IO` with randomness, as here, then the answer is just to lump your `State` actions together into one with the `Monad` operations (they're the thing passing the state around for you!).

```
test :: Int -> IO ()
test seed = do
  print a
  print b
  print c
  print d
  where
  (a,b,c,d) = flip evalState (mkStdGen seed) $ do
    a <- roll
    b <- roll
    c <- roll2
    d <- roll2
    return (a,b,c,d)
```

If you will need to interleave `IO` and randomness, then you will want to look into `StateT StdGen IO` as your monad instead of using `State StdGen` and `IO` separately. That might look like this, say:

```
roll :: MonadState StdGen m => m Int
roll = state (randomR (1,6))

roll2 :: MonadState StdGen m => m Int
roll2 = (+) <$> roll <*> roll

test :: (MonadState StdGen m, MonadIO m) => m ()
test = do
  roll >>= liftIO . print
  roll >>= liftIO . print
  roll2 >>= liftIO . print
  roll2 >>= liftIO . print
```

(You could then use e.g. `evalStateT test (mkStdGen seed)` to turn this back into an `IO ()` action, or embed it into a larger computation if there were further random things you needed to generate and do `IO` about.)

`MonadRandom` does little more than package up `StateT StdGen` in a way that lets you still use non-seed state, so I encourage you to reconsider using it. `evalRand` and `evalRandT` from `Control.Monad.Random.Lazy` (or `.Strict`) shouldy give you the repeatability you need; if they don't, you should open a fresh question with the full details of what you tried and how it went wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Wagner - this really clarifies things for me - I don't need to interleave so the first approach should be fine.  I will have another look at MonadRandom when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it's pretty much the whole point of a random generator that you *don't* always get the same result. And that's the reason why you use a state monad: to pass on the *updated* generator, so that the next random event will actually be different.

If you want always the same value, then there's not really any reason to use special random tooling at all – just generate one value once (or two values), then pass it on whereever needed, like you would pass on another variable.

```
test :: IO ()
test = do
   [dice0, dice1] <- replicateM 2 $ randomRIO (1,6)
   print dice0
   print dice0
   print $ dice0+dice1
   print $ dice0+dice1
```

Comment: The point is reproducibility. Pseudo-randomness is required for effects such as backoff, dithering, standard noise functions and so on. Being able to test a dithering algorithm by repeatedly using the same RNG (in quotes) sequence is very useful.

Comment: @BobDalgleish sure, but a dithering algorithm that uses the same brightness tweak _for every pixel_ wouldn't accomplish anything. The trick is to seed it always with the same constant _at the beginning_ of the program, but then propagate/update the generator throughout, so that values _within_ the program run vary. (Whether you want corresponding values in different program runs to be the same depends on the application.)

Comment: For my application I wanted to choose a seed at the start and then for exactly the same sequence of random numbers to be produced - that's what I was meaning by repeatability.  The point is that I want the roll function to produce a random number each time so it might or might not be the same as previously. @Bob Dalgleish, "Reproducibility" is I think a better word to describe what I need.  My primary reason for this is that I want to create random data but if I discover a bug or problem with my software I want to be able to reproduce the exact same random sequence so I can debug the issue.

Comment: @Adahus ok, that makes much more sense. Unfortunately your question was phrased rather ambiguously. And I couldn't see you meaning that, because it's _just what the random/state monad does_.

Comment: @leftroundabout - I'll edit the question to make this clearer. Thanks

Comment: TBH it's hardly clearer with only that one word substituted... but anyway, I suppose Daniel's answer is what you were looking for, right?